# How to call openURLContexts when app is open on app is not in memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13

I am trying to open the app using deeplink and using that deeplink I want to open a specified view.

Currently, I successfuly open the app using deeplink and go to the specified view when app is on background. But I cannot go to sepcified view using deeplink when app is not in memory. (still app is open)

This is the code I use.

```
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene openURLContexts:(NSSet<UIOpenURLContext *> *)URLContexts {
    for(UIOpenURLContext* element in URLContexts){
        NSLog(@"URL ::::::::: %@",element.URL);
        NSURL *url = element.URL;
    }
}
```

It seems openURLContexts not call when App is not in memory -> use deeplink to open the app.
Is there a way call openURLContexts or there is another method to integrate?

Comment: How `openURL` got called if application in foreground?

Comment: Use `willConnectTo`. The URL is in the `options`.

Comment: @matt If you don't mind, can you give me a sample code?

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/debd07d68c0ade33d36c5cf92c78a854cb9d871c/bk2ch23p802fileHandoff/ch36p1060fileHandoff/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: @matt Thanks for the tip.  I solve the problem.